# Laravel rewrite $model->someQueryHere->get()

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a class `SomeModel`. It is child of `SomeParentModel`. `SomeParentModel` is an EloquentORM model, and it works great. What i want to do is use custom `get()` method in `SomeModel` query builder.

```
$someModel
    ->where('something')
    ->andWhere('something')
    ->orderBy('field')
    ->get()
//    ^^^
// This method must to be custom
```

I tried to use [Model scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#local-scopes), but it seems like this is dont work for defaults.

```
public function scopeGet($query)
    {
        $query = $this->filter($query);

        dd('I`m tried :( This code not running, because i dont see this messsage');

        return $query;
    }

public function filter($query;)
    {
        if ($this->id) {
            $query->where('id', $this->id);
            return $query
        }

        if ($this->name) {
            $query->where('name', 'like', "%$this->name%");
        }

        if ($this->phone) {
            $query->whereHas('phones', function (Builder $q) {
                $q->where('number', 'like', "%$this->phone%");
            });
        }

        return $query;
    }
```

How can i do that?

Comment: Have you tried raw query for this?

Comment: what customization you want to do in `get()` method

Comment: I want to use field of `$someModel` as filter paramethers. In `get()` method of `SomeClass` i want to use query instructions like `$query->where('name', $this->name);`

Comment: @HassaanAli, in my case it is not correct. I will use this code in other models, or make `Trait` on its base.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you're aiming at by overriding the `get()` method but you can do the following:

All models that you've got extend from `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`
https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html

You can create a new class, that inherits from this Model, you override the method you want and then your `SomeModel` extends this new class you've just created.

I suggest however (I can't think of a funcionality where you want to override this) that you create a scope (or even global scope) if you plan on having a different build up.

Answer (score 1):

You question is still not fully clear. But if you want to create something like your filter() method. Laravel offers an [when()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#conditional-clauses) method.

This means you can do something like:

```
$someModel
    ->when($id = $this->id, function($query) use ($id) {
        $query->where('id', $id)
     })
    ->when($name = $this->name, function($query) use ($name) {
        $query->where('name', $name)
     })
    ->when($phone = $this->phone, function($query) use ($phone) {
        $query->whereHas('phones', function (Builder $q) {
            $q->where('number', 'like', "%" . $phone);
        });
     })
    ->orderBy('field')
    ->get();
```